# How To get previous date when subtracted from current date with no. of days in php

Tags: php, date

I am using a search option for retrieving data from database. The search criteria is between two dates. The default 'to date' is current system date and is using date() function. I want to set default 'from date' by 30 days less than current date. For example my 'To date, is 22-12-2014 then 'From date' be 22-11-2014. How can it set in php?

Comment: There are quite a few questions which are pretty much exactly the same here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**try this**

```
$to_date = date('d-m-Y');
$from_date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime("-1 month")); // or -30 days
```

Comment: I removed the current date from `strtotime` because it was not really needed (although it was not incorrect)